# Mongoose populate method isn't working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Good day:

Having an issue populating my *scope* path with mongoose. This is my collection for *Client*:

```
[
    {
        "_id": { "$oid": "5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4" },
        "name": "DFFDAFDAFA",
        "address": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "UNKNOWN",
        "telephone": "",
        "owner": true,
        "url": "",
        "client": "local",
        "client_secret": "DFDFADFAFD",
        "email": "email"
    }
]
```

This is my collection for *Scope*:

```
[
    {
        "client": "5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4",
        "service": "5a0707adbd0bea2dbf02daf9",
        "grant" : "5a074b7e3eba70336e172ddc"
    }
]
```

The following code is what I used to querying however, my *scope* path isn't being populated:

```
async getClient (clientId, clientSecret, callback) {
        let client = await this.connection.getClient().findOne({"client" : clientId, "client_secret" : clientSecret}).populate('scope');
        console.log(client);
    }
```

The output from the above code is:

```
{ _id: 5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4,
  name: 'DFFDAFDAFA',
  address: '',
  city: '',
  country: 'UNKNOWN',
  telephone: '',
  owner: true,
  url: '',
  client: 'local',
  client_secret: 'DFDFADFAFD',
  email: 'email' }
```

These are the Schemas:

`Client Schema:`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ClientSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    country: String,
    telephone: String,
    owner: Boolean,
    url: String,
    client: String,
    scopes : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Scope' }]
});

export default ClientSchema;
```

`Scope Schema:`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ScopeSchema = Schema({
    client: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' }],
    service: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service' }],
    grant: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Grant' }]
});

export default ScopeSchema;
```

Comment: See how `"client": "5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4",` looks like that yet your log from the other collection `"_id": { "$oid": "5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4" },` looks different. This would indicate that the `"client"` value in the scope collection is in fact stored as a string, and not an `ObjectId` as defined in the schema or in the related data. You can verify this for certain using the mongo shell, which prints with "type" information showing `ObjectId()` as a wrapping function where it truly is. If this is the case, then your scope collection needs the data to be fixed to be `ObjectId` values.

Comment: So use the mongo shell to take a real look and see what the actual type is. If they are in fact different as they appear to be, then this explains why populate is not working.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks...will check it out and write back to confirm.